# Unable to open signed APK from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am able to run an android app no problem, when I just hit the 'Run' button in android studio.  However, when I generate a signed APK from android studio I am unable to run the app from the signed APK.  I am able to install it but not run it.

I even put the app onto Google Play for an alpha test and the same error occurs.  I am able to download it, but not run it.

My build variant is release mode.

Any thoughts as to why I can't open the app?

[image: App Installation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you are probably using `proguard`, causing problem during the runtime.

You can check if you are using it if you have this line on your gradle file:  `minifyEnabled true`

If so, then open your file called `proguard-rules.pro` and try to edit the properties of your app, because probably proguard is shrinking or removing useful classes, causing your app to crash at launch as the device failed to find the necessary class or the good ones.

If you are not using proguard, plug the phone on your IDE and check the logcat: you will be able to see why your app is crashing at launch. This problem can come from a bad class cast, from the `multiDexEnabled` parameter, etc... in which case we need to know more.

Comment: The weird thing is that it runs perfectly fine when I run it directly from android studio in build mode or debug mode.  Also I checked and I'm not running proguard.  It doesn't even just crash directly on launch either...  It just never gives me the option to open the app at all.  Could it matter that my application uses a webview with js enabled?

Comment: Launching it with the IDE is different than running it from an APK. It doesnt use the same parameters, for example using google map from the IDE could work when it will not work if you launch it from the APK. It uses different certificates. Plug your device on your computer, launch your ide, check the logcat while trying to open your app. You have no others ways to figure out.

Comment: After trying to install the APK the only error I found was  E/AppIncrementalLogger: No apps are found for package name 'com.snappdigital.snappphilips'  but I'm not sure if that is making it crash?

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly set your default activity on the manifest? Because that would explaina  lot: probably the IDE has a default activity to launch, but it might not be the case from the APK if you didnt set the default activity

Comment: This is my activity  in the manifest `      <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`  Could it be that it is using the LEANBACK LAUNCHER?

Comment: use something like:


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 1):

Add your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```